# Stable and reliable OAuth client proof

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

In OAuth, client_id and client_secret are enough to prove that you are a client. I think that's not enough, so I thought about adding a client's authority check (e.g. if his domain matches the one stored in the server's database), but the Origin header can be forged by anyone. Is there anything on which the client's authority can be reliably based? I have one idea, but it seems weak because in this idea the server has to send a request to the client to confirm that he sent the request and not someone else. In other words, is it possible to uniquely identify the source of the http request?

Comment: I see you only have a [so] account, but this isn't a programming question. Why not ask on [security.se]? Please try and make your question as descriptive as possible though, I'm not sure if your idea can be fully understood at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know there was such a thing as Information Security. I modified my question a bit, do you understand me now?

Answer (score 0):

There are two stronger forms of the OAuth client secret, where proof of ownership of a cryptographic private key is sent:

- [Client certificates](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oidc-spring-boot-mtls-auth/)
- [Client assertions](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-assertion/)

Both of these do not reveal secrets in HTTP messages. They are standard solutions and pretty widely used.

The first option tends to require an extra token endpoint that requires Mutual TLS, whereas the second can be easier to manage.

Comment: These are good solutions, but I mean something more "physical". Same as the client's IP but must be something that cannot be impersonated or it is very difficult to do and this identifier must remain the same until changed by a person (IP can be changed by DHCP)